# Python CVS file and DataFrames

Tags: python

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv('/content/drive/My Drive/top_100_books-Kevin_Mulach.csv')
i = 0
ratingbyprice = []

for book in Books['title']:
  if book == 'Man\'s Search for Meaning':
    Books['price'][i] = 9.99

  if book == 'Rich Dad Poor Dad':
   Books['type'][i] = 'Paperback'

ratingbyprice.append(Books['rating'][i]/Books['price'][i])

i += 1
```

Question: What would define books as in my code I am not sure?

Comment: check weather Books['rating']/Books['price']  column does not contain Nan value

Answer (score 0):

This should be your code:

```
import pandas as pd
Books = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/My Drive/top_100_books-Kevin_Mulach.csv')
i = 0
ratingbyprice = []

for book in Books['title']:
  if book == 'Man\'s Search for Meaning':
    Books['price'][i] = 9.99

  if book == 'Rich Dad Poor Dad':
   Books['type'][i] = 'Paperback'

  ratingbyprice.append(Books['rating'][i]/Books['price'][i])

  i += 1
```